# Regex not working validation control

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am new to Regex, I have a Regex expression in an `asp.net ExpressionValidator` with this expression in it to validate an email address.

The problem is it won't validate the email when the `us.af.mil` is in capital letters. The error I get is:

> unexpected qualifier

All the other times all it recognizes is the lower case part of the email. I have tried several other variations on the code and nothing works. I am sure I am leaving something out but not sure what. Listed below are some of the variations. Hope someone can tell me what I am leaving out.

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@(?i:(us.af.mil))
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@(us.af.mil)|(US.AF.MIL)
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@uUsS.aAfF.mMiIlL
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@(?i)(us.af.mil)
```

Comment: First, the `.` in `us.af.mil` needs to be escaped (`\.`), otherwise it matches *any* character. --- #1 and #4 should work, but you don't need the extra `()`: #1 `@(?i:us\.af\.mil)`, #4 `@(?i)us\.af\.mil` --- #2 doesn't work because the `|` is an OR between everything on its left and everything on its right. You need to surround the OR group with `()`, and the extra `()` you have are unnecessary: #2 `@(us\.af\.mil|US\.AF\.MIL)` --- #3 definitely doesn't work. Maybe you meant `@[uU][sS]\.[aA][fF]\.[mM][iI][lL]`?

Comment: I tried 1,2,4 and could only get no. 2 to work. I still get the error Unexpected quantifier when I tried 1 and 4.  Does asp.net validation expression not recognize the ?i qualifier.

Comment: The [Regular Expressions in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx) page does *not* list the `(?i)` mode modifier.

Comment: According to this Microsoft site it is a modifier.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#Case

Comment: According to some .NET site, perhaps, but the ASP.NET *Microsoft* page I linked to does not list any modifiers. Don't know what version of .NET your ASP.NET is using. Your *empirical evidence* is that modifiers don't work, and the page I listed don't show that they should.